# Duplicate vim buffer

Tags: vim, buffer

I would like to duplicate the current buffer, which will act the same way only that I will use the rtl command on it:

`:set rightleft`

Except that the buffers will be the same, if I scroll down in the original one the second will scroll too and etc.

Is it possible in vim without any plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
just split it
`:sp` or `:vsp` and then use the following:

```
 :windo set scrollbind
```

`windo` will send the command to every open windo see `:h windo`
and `scrollbind` is what you are really looking for again see `:h scrollbind` for more

The `rightleft` or `rl` command is local to the window, so you can view the same buffer in two different windows with and without `rl`

Comment: Thank I'll try it. I have one problem with the windo commands but I just might not be familiar with it enough, will it bind the scrolling in all buffers on current window?

Comment: it will do the scrollbinding in every window (or split) you have open in your vim. `bufdo` will do it on all buffers no matter if you see them or not. You could also activate it on a per window basis with `set scrollbind` which will only set it to `true` for the active window. I hope this helps. If it is still unclear just ask again